# Installing AutoSKLearn in Anaconda Environment

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to install autosklearn in anaconda environment [AutoSKLearn](https://automl.github.io/auto-sklearn/stable/installation.html#installing-auto-sklearn), after that i am using jupyter notebook and trying to `import autosklearn.classification` but i got this error, "ValueError: numpy.ufunc size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 216 from C header, got 192 from PyObject". How i can fix this error ?

Answer (score 0):

Everyghing is explained [here](https://automl.github.io/auto-sklearn/master/installation.html#installing-auto-sklearn).

> **Anaconda installation**
>   Anaconda does not ship auto-sklearn, and there are no conda packages
>   for auto-sklearn. Thus, it is easiest to install auto-sklearn as
>   detailed in the Section Installing auto-sklearn.
>
> A common installation problem under recent Linux distribution is the
>   incompatibility of the compiler version used to compile the Python
>   binary shipped by AnaConda and the compiler installed by the
>   distribution. This can be solved by installing the gcc compiler
>   shipped with AnaConda (as well as swig):
>
> `conda install gxx_linux-64 gcc_linux-64 swig`

Comment: I have installed linux package. What is next now? Running conda install autosklearn does not help. Could you please?

Answer (score 0):

As per autosklearn documentation, it won't officially supports on windows,

```
auto-sklearn relies heavily on the Python module resource. resource is part of Python’s Unix Specific Services and not available on a Windows machine. Therefore, it is not possible to run auto-sklearn on a Windows machine.

Possible solutions (not tested):

Windows 10 bash shell

virtual machine

docker image
```

Answer (score 0):

**** How to install auto-sklearn and pyrtr on Mac OS Big Sur 11.2.1 and gcc 10.2.04 ****

This is how I successfully installed auto-sklearn on Mac OS Big Sur, under Anaconda 3

The bottleneck was to use the latest gcc compiler to install pyrfr, which is a dependency for auto-sklearn, and a couple of other things.
On Mac OS, C++ and dev tools are installed with xcode-select, and the default version of C++ compiler is not the one we need (refer to this [thread](https://github.com/automl/auto-sklearn/issues/101)):

> gcc --version

The default is being /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang

First, make sure everything is updated:

> xcode-select --install

> brew update
> brew upgrade
> brew info gcc
> brew install gcc
> brew cleanup
> brew doctor

And update conda too, just in case:

> conda update -n base conda
> conda update --all

("conda install gcc" wouldn't work for me, like some threads suggested, and "conda config --set restore_free_channel true" did not help either)
if "frozen"

> conda update -prefix /opt/anaconda3 anaconda

But "brew install gcc" installed gcc for me, and now all we need to make an alias in ~/.zshrc (or ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc, if you have not switch to use zsh, which is the default in newer Mas OS)

> brew gcc info
> gcc: stable 10.2.0 (bottled), HEAD
> GNU compiler collection
> https://gcc.gnu.org/
> /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0_4

Suggested, my gcc now is in /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0_4/bin/gcc-10
Check:
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0_4/bin/gcc-10 -v

Making an alias:

> vi ~/.zshrc
> add alias
> alias gcc="/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0_4/bin/gcc-10"
> source ~/.zshrc

Now, proceed with installations:

> brew install swig
> pip install lazy-import
> pip install pyrfr --no-cache-dir
> pip install auto-sklearn --no-cache-dir

Done!

Maybe, this helps:

> pip uninstall pyrfr auto-sklearn
> curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/automl/auto-sklearn/master/requirements.txt | xargs -n 1 -L 1 pip install
> CC=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0_4/bin/gcc-10 pip install lazy-import pyrfr auto-sklearn --no-cache-dir

Or, if you managed to install gcc in Anaconda3:

> pip uninstall pyrfr auto-sklearn
> curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/automl/auto-sklearn/master/requirements.txt | xargs -n 1 -L 1 pip install
> CC=/Users//opt/anaconda3/bin/gccpip install pyrfr auto-sklearn --no-cache-dir

Maybe, you need to re-install auto-sklearn, then

> pip install autosklearn --no-cache-dir --force-reinstall -I --no-deps --upgrade

Additional resources, that might help to get there:
https://medium.com/@dvdasari/install-latest-gcc-on-mac-os-x-b4ce9a66a184
[http://www-scf.usc.edu/~csci104/installation/gccmac.html](http://www-scf.usc.edu/%7Ecsci104/installation/gccmac.html)
https://github.com/automl/auto-sklearn/issues/155

Answer (score 0):

Try:
`conda install -c conda-forge auto-sklearn`

https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/auto-sklearn